# Complete camera hardware control

Tags: android, android-camera

I was reading the article released by Google on [Portrait mode](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/10/portrait-mode-on-pixel-2-and-pixel-2-xl.html) for their Pixel-2, wherein they have explained their approach. In their, they mention, how they have used the PDAF system, for computing the depth map.

I am trying to find if there is a way for manipulating this sensor using Android Studio. or If there is any other way, for manipulating the sensor, using any other approach etc.

How does, one have complete access to the Camera imaging pipeline in android?.